# How return element of nested promise in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have created the following function in protractor:

```
function getChildElementByText(parentElement, tagName, textToSearch)
{
    return parentElement.all(by.tagName(tagName))
    .then((items) => {
      items.map( item => {
        item.getText().then(text => {
          if (text === textToSearch){
            return item;
          }
        });
      });
    });
}
```

Example to get the `<option>` elements of a `<select>` element:

```
let myitem = selectorHelpers.getChildElementByText(clientIdSelect, 'option', 'ExampleText');
myitem.click();
```

This give me the following error:

```
Failed: myitem.click is not a function
```

I need the function to return the item which match the text criteria for then click that element as show in above example.

Comment: Your first `.then`'s callback doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Where should be the return of the first .then? Sorry I'm beginner in javascript promises.

Comment: There is only one expression in that callback *to* return, `items.map(...)`. But the callback to that map doesn't return anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` to get a single element might not be the best way. `map` returns a new array based on the returned value of each item.

Consider using a `for...or` or even a classic `for` loop to loop over each item and use `async / await` to wait for each `item.getText()` to resolve before continuing to the next item. Then if the awaited result equals the `textToSearch` return the `item` object. Otherwise return `null` after the loop.

```
function getChildElementByText(parentElement, tagName, textToSearch) {
  return parentElement.all(by.tagName(tagName))
    .then(async items => {
      for (const item of items) {
        const text = await item.getText();
        if (text === textToSearch) {
          return item;
        }
      }
      return null;
    });
}
```